# resolve to variable for if-statement

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

im trying to complete my if statement and i can not resolve the winChance into a variable inside the if statement, if someone could show me hoew it would be greatly appreciated. the ereor is in ' goal before going broke is: " + winChance ); ' and my last winChance method is not returning a double variable'

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StockiColeA1Q3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner

    System.out.println("What is your first name? "); 
    String first = keyboard.nextLine(); 

    System.out.println("What is your last name? "); 
    String last = keyboard.nextLine();  

    System.out.println("What is the amount of chips you are starting with, " + first +"?"); 
    int start = keyboard.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("What is the amount of chips you wish you have ?");
    int end = keyboard. nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("What is the probability of each round? \n" + 
                         "(A value between 0.0 and 1.0)"); 
    double p = keyboard.nextDouble(); 

    printResult(start,end,p,first,last); 

  }//main

  public static void printResult(int start, int end, double p, String first, String last)  {

    System.out.println(first + " " + last +": If you start with " + start + " chips\n" +
                         "And do not quit until you have " + end + " chips,\n" +
                       "with the probability of " + p + " of winning each round, \n" +
                       "the chance of reaching your goal before going broke is: " + winChance );  

  }//print results 

  public static double winChance(double start, double end, double p)   {


    if (p==0.5) { 
     System.out.println(start/end); 

    }       
    else if (p>0&&p<1)  {  
     System.out.println(1-(Math.pow((1-p)/p, start))/1-(Math.pow((1-p)/p, end))); 

    }//if p isnt 0.5
  }//win chance 

}//gamblers ruin
```

Comment: You aren't actually declaring a variable called winChance

Answer (score 0):

```
if (p==0.5) { 
 System.out.println(start/end);
 **return (start/end);**

}       
else if (p>0&&p<1)  {  
 System.out.println(1-(Math.pow((1-p)/p, start))/1-(Math.pow((1-p)/p, end)));
 **return (1-(Math.pow((1-p)/p, start))/1-(Math.pow((1-p)/p, end)));**

}//if p isnt 0.5
```

Make sure you return something right now you aren't returning anything.

Comment: Try this make sure you return the double otherwise you will get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add brackets to the end of "winChance" inside the print statement, along with the arguments. Right now the compiler thinks you are using a variable and not a method call.

For example

```
System.out.println(first + " " + last +": If you start with " + start + " chips\n" +
                     "And do not quit until you have " + end + " chips,\n" +
                   "with the probability of " + p + " of winning each round, \n" +
                   "the chance of reaching your goal before going broke is: " + winChance(start, end, p) );
```

You will also need to follow brso05's answer and return a value inside the winChance method.

P.S I'm guessing that you mean to use return instead of System.out.println() in your winChance method, if so, use the following instead:

```
if (p==0.5) { 
    return start/end; 
}       
else if (p>0&&p<1)  {  
    return 1-(Math.pow((1-p)/p, start))/1-(Math.pow((1-p)/p, end)); 
}
```

You might want to read up more about using methods inJava, try this  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm